# Sum of result generated at run time in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, runtime

I have a table in MySQL which has a lot of data. I want to show sum of the generated column...

I am subtracting two columns and I want to show SUM of the result. Here is what I have

```
 CREATE TABLE amounts(
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
bank_amount INT,
amount INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO `amounts` (`id`, `bank_amount`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, '1000', '100'),
(NULL, '2000', '200'),(NULL, '3000', '300'),(NULL, '1200', '500'),(NULL, '2000', '600'),
(NULL, '1202',   '800'),(NULL, '220', '50');
```

I have this query

```
SELECT bank_amount,amount,(bank_amount-amount) as bal from amounts where ......
```

Above query will give me this result

bank_amount  amount   bal

1000          100     900

2000          200     1800

3000          300     2700

and so on

Now I want to show SUM of bal also like 900+1800+2700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT x.*
      , x.bank_amount-x.amount bal
      , SUM(y.bank_amount-y.amount) running
   FROM amounts x
   JOIN amounts y
     ON y.id <= x.id
  GROUP
     BY id;
 +----+-------------+--------+------+---------+
 | id | bank_amount | amount | bal  | running |
 +----+-------------+--------+------+---------+
 |  1 |        1000 |    100 |  900 |     900 |
 |  2 |        2000 |    200 | 1800 |    2700 |
 |  3 |        3000 |    300 | 2700 |    5400 |
 |  4 |        1200 |    500 |  700 |    6100 |
 |  5 |        2000 |    600 | 1400 |    7500 |
 |  6 |        1202 |    800 |  402 |    7902 |
 |  7 |         220 |     50 |  170 |    8072 |
 +----+-------------+--------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.bank_amount,
    A.amount,
    (A.bank_amount - A.amount) as bal,
    T.Total_bal
FROM amounts A
    JOIN 
      (
          SELECT Id, SUM(bank_amount-amount) Total_bal
          FROM amounts
          GROUP BY Id
      ) T
      ON A.Id = T.Id
```

?

Comment: This will generate SUM for each row...i want sum of whole result.For example lets say i have this...1000 100 900 in first row and in second row i have this...2000 200 1800.Now i need result of 900+1800

Comment: @Methew What is wrong? You get exact that you want. Are you tried the query?

Comment: @Methew Do you want to get this result for each `Id` and have you many rows for each `Id`?

Comment: I am getting correct result for bal for each Id.i have many rows for each Id.Now i want to sum all of bal field

Comment: For Example,Customer1 have to pay for two invoices(invoice1 has 500 and invoice2 has 400)..he paid 200 for invoice1 so remaining is 300.For invoice2 he paid 300 so 100 remains in invoice2.i need remaining of both invoices..like 300+100=400

Comment: I need this query,SELECT bank_amount,amount,(bank_amount-amount) as bal from amounts where....how to modify it to do above work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24660/discussion-between-methew-and-hamlet-hakobyan)